# Как правильно делать запись в json (PYTHON)

Tags: python, json

***Привет, я хотел бы реализовать свою идею с никнеймами.
У меня есть json, но проблема в том, как правильно туда записывать данные?***

**nicks.txt**

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "user_319990365": [
                {
                    "nick" : "developer"
                }
            ],
            "user_1": [
                {
                    "nick" : "admin"
                }
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

Как вы наверное поняли, мне надо в "players" создать "user_АЙДИЮЗЕРА" с параметрами "nick": "текст".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы храните данные в словаре, то воспользуйтесь библиотекой `json`

```
import json
    
# Data to be written
dictionary ={
    "name" : "sathiyajith",
    "rollno" : 56,
    "cgpa" : 8.6,
    "phonenumber" : "9976770500"
}
    
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(dictionary, outfile)
```

[Исходик примера](https://geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-python-dictionary-to-json/)

Comment: а как записать значение в массив?

Comment: Если вы имели ввиду список, то метод `append()`